# How do I edit my username in the Stack Exchange app?

Tags: support

How do I change my name and avatar in the Stack Exchange app for Android? I don't see an "Edit Profile" link or button anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using the official [Stack Exchange](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) Android app, it does not yet provide the functionality to edit your own profile. The app is fairly new though, so this feature may appear in future versions.

In the meantime you can edit your profile on the Stack Exchange web site.